# Size of pointers to pointers in memory

Tags: c, memory, pointers

Just a quick question:

on a 32 bit machine, is a pointer to a pointer (`**p`) going to be 4 bytes?

Comment: Yes, at least usually (i.e., there might be some oddball system that's normally thought of as "32-bit" where it's not true, but if so, it's pretty obscure).

Comment: Any reason why it shouldn't be?

Comment: reason it might not is that a compiler might try to do something cunning for some reason depending on the processor architecture, ie, it might be 8 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic is that pointers are merely memory addresses. The memory address of *any* stored entity in a machine with 32-bit addresses is almost certainly 4 bytes.  Therefore the memory address of a stored pointer is 4 bytes.  Therefore a pointer to a pointer is 4 bytes.  None of this is promised by the ISO C standard.  It's just the way that nearly all implementations turn out.

Answer (score 2):

yes... it will be 4 bytes... but its not guaranteed.

Comment: what do u mean by "but its not guaranteed."?

Comment: there isn't a spec that says it HAS to be that, but typically compilers DO make it 4.

Answer (score 1):

Correct. Pointers usually have a fixed size. On a 32-bit machine they are usually 32 bits (= 4 bytes)

Answer (score 1):

Typically yes, addresses on 32-bit machines it will be 4 bytes.

Best bet if you don't want to make assumptions is run the old `sizeof(p)`

Answer (score 1):

Others have already mentioned that it's most certainly 32 bits or 4 8-bit bytes.

However, depending on the hardware and the compiler it may be less or more than that.

If your machine can address its memory only as 32-bit units at 32-bit boundaries, you will have to have a bigger pointer to address and access 8-bit portions (`chars`/`bytes`) of every 32-bit memory cell. If the compiler here decides not to have pointers of different sizes, all pointers (including pointers to pointers) become 34+-bit long.

Likewise, if the program is very small and can fit into 64KB, the compiler may be able to reduce all pointers to 16 bits.